# Moving picturebox randomly in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, picturebox

```
Const StepSize As Integer = 1  '-- increase or decrease this to move the block fast or slow.
Private Random As New Random

Public BulletMovement As System.Drawing.Point
Public bullet_case

Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Asteroid1Movement.Interval = 1
    Asteroid1Movement.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Asteroid1Movement_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Asteroid1Movement.Tick
    Dim direction As Integer = Random.Next(0, 4)

    Select Case direction
        Case 0 'Upwards
            Asteroid1.Top -= StepSize
            If Asteroid1.Top < 0 Then Asteroid1.Top = 0
        Case 1 'Downwards
            Asteroid1.Top += StepSize
            If Asteroid1.Top > Me.Height - Asteroid1.Height Then Asteroid1.Top = Me.Height - Asteroid1.Height
        Case 2 'Left
            Asteroid1.Left -= StepSize
            If Asteroid1.Left < 0 Then Asteroid1.Left = 0
        Case 3 'Right
            Asteroid1.Left += StepSize
            If Asteroid1.Left > Me.Width - Asteroid1.Width Then Asteroid1.Left = Me.Width - Asteroid1.Width
    End Select
End Sub
```

I am trying to code the game Asteroids, and I am currently working on making the asteroids move around the screen randomly. This code works sort of, as it does make the asteroid move, but not around the entire screen as I want it to.

I understand you can't "do my homework for me", but can you give help me in any way? I have been working on this for 3-4 days already.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. In the game Asteroids, the actual asteroids don't move randomly. Once on a path, they continue on that path until they are shot. The random element should only affect the initial size and initial trajectory of an asteroid when it first appears and the trajectory of a chunk of an asteroid that was just shot.

Comment: OK, I didn't know that the asteroids didn't move randomly. You learn something new every day! Would you be able give me the basic code to allow me to start coding the asteroids to move along a path please.

Comment: "OK, I didn't know that the asteroids didn't move randomly".  I guess you're not old enough to have actually played the game in an arcade then. ;-)  "Would you be able give me the basic code to allow me to start coding the asteroids to move along a path please".  I'm afraid that that is not what this site is for.